# Can -ms-filter styles be themeable in SharePoint?

Tags: css, sharepoint, internet-explorer-8, sharepoint-2010

We have the following themeable styles to have a gradient for the background of the webpart body:

```
.ms-wpContentDivSpace{
    /* For Non-CSS3 Browsers */
    background: /* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Light2-Lightest")] */ transparent; 
    /* For Firefox 3.6+ */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, 
        /* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Light2-Lightest")] */ #FEFEFB, 
        /* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Light2-Lighter")] */ #E9E9E9);
    /* For WebKit (Safari, Chrome, etc.) */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, 
        from(/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Light2-Lightest")] */ #FEFEFB), 
        to(/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Light2-Lighter")] */ #E9E9E9));
    /* For Internet Explorer */ 
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0, 
        startColorstr=/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Light2-Lightest")] */ #FEFEFB, 
        endColorstr=/*[ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Light2-Lighter")]*/ #E9E9E9);
    -ms-filter:'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0, 
        startColorstr=/*[ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Light2-Lightest")]*/ #FEFEFB, 
        endColorstr=/*[ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Light2-Lighter")]*/ #E9E9E9)'; 
}
```

All of it works fine except for the -ms-filter style for IE8. I've tried every combination of escaping the quotes and slashes and single vs double quotes, but the only way I can get it to work is to remove the ReplaceColor instructions:

```
.ms-wpContentDivSpace{
    /* For Non-CSS3 Browsers */
    background: /* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Light2-Lightest")] */ transparent; 
    /* For Firefox 3.6+ */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, 
        /* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Light2-Lightest")] */ #FEFEFB, 
        /* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Light2-Lighter")] */ #E9E9E9);
    /* For WebKit (Safari, Chrome, etc.) */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, 
        from(/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Light2-Lightest")] */ #FEFEFB), 
        to(/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Light2-Lighter")] */ #E9E9E9));
    /* For Internet Explorer */ 
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0, 
        startColorstr=/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Light2-Lightest")] */ #FEFEFB, 
        endColorstr=/*[ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Light2-Lighter")]*/ #E9E9E9);
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0, 
        startColorstr=#FEFEFB, 
        endColorstr=#E9E9E9)"; 
}
```

Is it possible to have -ms-filter support themeable styles?

**UPDATE:**

It actually works as expected when a theme is applied. The problem is that when no theme is selected, the gradient is blue on top and dark blue on bottom. So it seems to be working up to the first comment slash because the rendered result is the same as if the style did not specify colors:

```
-ms-filter:'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0)';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how we fixed it. We have two style sheets that were identical, but placed in different directories:

- 14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\1033\STYLES\MyProject\MyStyles.css
- 14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\1033\STYLES\Themable\MyProject\MyStyles.css

Our custom master page points to the first style sheet. That is the style sheet that is used when the Theme is `Default (no theme)`. But when SharePoint goes to compile a selected theme, it uses the style sheet in the second directory.

We left the second style sheet alone because it was working when it is compiled into a theme. We then removed the theme directive comments from the filter styles in the first style sheet:

```
.ms-wpContentDivSpace{
    /* For Non-CSS3 Browsers */
    background: /* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Light2-Lightest")] */ transparent; 
    /* For Firefox 3.6+ */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, 
        /* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Light2-Lightest")] */ #FEFEFB, 
        /* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Light2-Lighter")] */ #E9E9E9);
    /* For WebKit (Safari, Chrome, etc.) */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, 
        from(/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Light2-Lightest")] */ #FEFEFB), 
        to(/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Light2-Lighter")] */ #E9E9E9));
    /* For Internet Explorer */ 
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0, 
        startColorstr=#FEFEFB, 
        endColorstr=#E9E9E9);
    -ms-filter:'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0, 
        startColorstr=#FEFEFB, 
        endColorstr=#E9E9E9)'; 
}
```

We tested it out and the gradient is now working, with or without a Theme, in IE7 & 8, FF and Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

You could get your theme to process the images for you - and that way you wouldn't need CSS for 3 different browsers. The themes in 2010 can recolour images (or areas in images)

e.g.

```
/* [RecolorImage(themeColor:"Dark2-Lighter",method:"Filling",includeRectangle:{x:0,y:467,width:1,height:11})] */ background:url("/_layouts/images/bgximg.png") repeat-x -0px -467px;
```

Which is pretty neat. When you apply your theme, the image (bgximg.png) will be processed and colours replaced and so on.

If you look through CoreV4.css there are examples. Or [this is an okay](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdesigner/archive/2010/04/09/working-with-the-sharepoint-theming-engine.aspx) description. Perhaps Tinting would be adequate?

Failing that, I'd try putting my Theme directives before where I use my colours, rather than in:

```
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Dark2",themeShade:"0.8")] */ background-color:#21374c;
```

Comment: I don't think bgximg.png will work. It's making my web part look like a rainbow. Also, I don't think this will give me smooth gradients over variable heights. But let me see if I understand the idea: let's say I create my own gradient image, E9E9E9.png, which is half transparent and half my default dark color. I could then do something like this: background: /* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Light2-Lightest")] */ #FEFEFB /* [RecolorImage(themeColor:"Light2-Lighter",method:"Tinting")] */ url("/_layouts/images/myproject/E9E9E9.png") repeat-x 0 bottom;

Comment: Lol - yes, that was just a random example straight from the CoreV4.CSS; I've no idea what it'd look like. But yes, you've got the idea; the RecolorImage directive tells SharePoint "When you apply this theme, go fetch this image and generate a new one based on this color/method". Note that the images are only generated when the theme is applied - so if you went and updated the CSS, you'd have to reapply the theme. Not sure I get what you mean about gradients over variable heights though - could you post an example?. And yes, I do think the Themes directives lack a 'Gradient Fill' option...

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [CSS3Pie](http://www.css3pie.com/)?

This is a hack for IE, which allows it to recognise certain CSS3 properties using the standard syntax. It includes gradient backgrounds.

Using CSS3Pie means you can forget about ever having to use those horrible `filer` and `-ms-filter` properties, at least for gradients.

It's also great for supporting `border-radius`, which is probably its most popular feature.

Hope that helps.